# Should I use Camera2 or Camera APIs for Android?

Tags: android, camera

Android released a new version of Camera APIs called [camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html), I want to use them on my app since I had a lot of issue with the old APIs and I hope that the new camera management APIs are better. The problem I have the majority of users on older Android devices, is there any compatibility package to handle this for you or do you have to write two different classes for each APIs?

Comment: I am curious to know the set of issues you encountered with Camera API as I am also investigating my iOS Camera app to Android. I need to tweak camera parameters like Focus, Exposure, WB, Frame rate, resolution, etc.

Comment: The main issue the I had is managing the different components of Camera and Camera view, also it's a pain to managing it with Android LifeCycle. I'm sure there's a lot of different issues, but I think these could be the main reason why they switched to a completely new APIs.

Comment: How about using cwac-camera framework ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is there any compatibility package to handle this for you

No, because that's not really possible -- Camera2 is different at a very low level. If anything, the old `android.hardware.Camera` API *is* the "compatibility package".

> do you have to write two different classes for each APIs?

I suspect that it will be many more than two different classes. But, yes, if you want to use both APIs, you will need to use *both* APIs.